# Why only update one data in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have below update statement, and I am sure there are more than one data by `{_id: {$in: ids}`, but only update one data.

can anybody help why does this happen?

```
UserModel.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, { $addToSet: { goods: goodsid }}, callback);
```

Comment: I marked your inline code with backticks (`\``) so it's formatted as code. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can format your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a third parameter with update options:

`UserModel.update({_id: {$in: ids}}, { $addToSet: { goods: goodsid }}, {multi: true}, callback);`

See:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update